# How to make Heritrix to continue crawl process on domains found and are not in seed list

Tags: web-crawler

How to make Heritrix to continue crawl process on domains found and are not in seed list?
I mean make it to not to stop after crawled over all Domains in seeds list. and continue the crawling process for each link it found in the crawling process.

Comment: The entire web? You're kidding, right?

Comment: @Bart Jiers: I mean make i to not to stop after crawled over all Domains in seeds. and continue the crawling process for each link it found in the crawling process.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I last worked with Heritrix, but if memory serves me well, you'll need to change the `max-link-hops` in your settings/profile. The larger you make `max-link-hops`, the more steps ("hops") Heritrix makes from the seed(s) you have defined.

Comment: Thanks; but there is no `max-link-hops`! there is `max-hop`; is it that? Is there an infinite value for it?

Comment: @Snigger, yeah, my guess is that `max-hop` is the one. I don't know if there's am infinite amount for it, perhaps 0 is infinite? Try it out. But I don't think setting it to infinite (or even a large value) is wise: chances are your crawl will simply be running for years (no kidding)! Unless you have a distributed setup consisting of thousands of machines with massive amounts of storage and bandwidth...

Answer (score 1):

By default Heritrix is configured to only crawl URLs on the domains that are in your seed list. Some additional material is also usually crawled as embedded material, hosted elsewhere, is also fetched.

If you would like Heritrix to crawl anything it comes across, you'll need to modify the scope.

The scope is composed of a series of decide rules. Each rule can ACCEPT, REJECT or pass on a URL. The last rule to either ACCEPT or REJECT wins. Typically, the first rule in the list is a blanket reject all, then followed by a SurtPrefixDecideRule that rules in all URLs that match the SURT list. The SURT list is typically built using the seed list.

You can however configure the SURT list manually be specifying your own, or (if you really want everything), you can simply remove it and the reject all rule and add an accept all decide rule to the top.

[More on configuring Heritrix 3 scoping.](https://webarchive.jira.com/wiki/display/Heritrix/Configuring+Crawl+Scope+Using+DecideRules)

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the surt decide rule 'NotonDomains' to true. This will crawl all domains which is not on the seedlist.